Upgrade plugin not downloading latest plugin data in QGIS
I have a custom plugin stored on a local server (repository). When I attempt to upgrade or reinstall the plugin, I receive a notification stating that the plugin has been upgraded/re-installed successfully;
however, the plugin does not reflect any of the latest data.
Everything appears to be fine regarding the plugin repository connection and XML schema, but I'm uncertain about why the plugins aren't updating to include the most recent data.
